# Process finished with exit code 0 в коде работы телеграмм бота

Tags: python, aiogram

`Process finished with exit code` процесс сам по себе завершается, не могу понять в чём причина

```
import openai
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

token = 'token'
openai.api_key = 'token'

bot = Bot(token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def send(message : types.Message):
    response = openai.completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-003",
        promt=message.text,
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=1000,
        top_p=1.0,
        frequency_penalty=0.5,
        presence_penalty=0.0,
    )

    await message.answer(response['choices'][0]['text'])
    
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Код в вопросе поехал, подправьте, пожалуйста

Comment: У вас `executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)` реально находится внутри функции `async def send(message : types.Message):` или это так тут разместилось?

Comment: подправил код, да реально находится

Comment: Подправил ваш пример. Решение проблемы вынести `executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)` из функции, тогда бот будет запущен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно вынести `executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)` из функции:

```
...
@dp.message_handler()
async def send(message : types.Message):
    ...
    await message.answer(response['choices'][0]['text'])
    
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Теперь бот должен запуститься и процесс не завершится, пока бот работает